# How to get everything outside the database with foreach and class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, while-loop

I have a problem. I want some data out my database.
I have two page's a categorie.php here I want that he shows everything out the database. And I have a second page. Here are my classes. I have trying a foreach on the categorie.php but if I do that, than shows he 1 thing out the database 4 times the same and not the another data. 
Below you can see my code.
I hope that you can help me.

Thank you.

This is my categorie.php

```
<?php
require_once '../app/functions/second.php';
require_once '../app/db/dbpassword.php';
require_once 'include/head.php';


if (isset($_GET['categorie']) && !empty($_GET['categorie'])) {
    $id = $_GET['categorie'];
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname;", $usernamedb, 
$passworddb);
    $cate = new Categorie($dbh);
    $cate->loadCate($id);
    // $page->loadId($id);
    $categorie = $cate->getCategorie();
    $titel = ucwords($categorie);

?>

<h2 class="center_h2"><?= $titel ?></h2>
<?php foreach ($cate as $key) {
        $titelart = $cate->getTitel();
    $beschrijving = $cate->getBeschrijving();
    $plaatje = $cate->getImage();
    $id = $cate->getId();
    var_dump($titelart);
} ?>


<?php 
} else {
    echo "Dit bericht is verwijderd of is verplaats.";
}
require_once 'include/footer.php';
?>
```

This is my class page

```
    <?php
    class Categorie {
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct($new_dbh){
        $this->dbh = $new_dbh;
    }

    public function loadCate($cate){
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM schilderijen WHERE categorie=?');
        $query->execute(array($cate));
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $this->id = $row->id;
        $this->categorie = $row->categorie;
        $this->titel = $row->titel;
        $this->beschrijving = $row->beschrijving;
        $this->plaatje = $row->plaatje;
        }


    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCategorie(){
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    public function getTitel(){
        return $this->titel;
    }

    public function getBeschrijving(){
        return $this->beschrijving;
    }

    public function getImage(){
        return $this->plaatje;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have a problem with the use of your class. In the `while` after your SQL request, you apply the value the instance variable like `$this->id = $row->id;` but this variable will be rewrite with the next row value.

Use a `static` function for your SQL request and return an array of `Categorie` like that :

```
class Categorie {
    protected $id, $categorie, $title, $beschrijving, $plaatje;

    public function __construct($id, $categorie, $title, $beschrijving, $plaatje){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->categorie = $categorie;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->beschrijving = $beschrijving;
        $this->plaatje = $plaatje;
    }

    public static function loadCate($dbh, $cate){
        $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM schilderijen WHERE categorie=?');
        $query->execute(array($cate));

        $res = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $res[] = new Categorie($row->id, $row->categorie, $row->titel, $row->beschrijving, $row->plaatje);
        }

        return $res;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCategorie(){
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getBeschrijving(){
        return $this->beschrijving;
    }

    public function getImage(){
        return $this->plaatje;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```
$categories = Categorie::loadCate($dbh, $id);
foreach($categories as $categorie){
    var_dump($categorie->getTitle());
}
```